# Running Scripts on Multiple Servers using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, dns, server

At work we have been assigned an additional server because the load for our current server is to much.

What I want to do now is have all my PHP Scripts on one Server ( Server 1) ran from another (server 2) to allow less stress on (server 1). Also I want to be able to have sub domain for server 2 on the same domain for server 1.

If anyone could point me in the right direction as to what I should be doing I would greatly appreciate this.

Thank you for any help.

Chithambaram

Comment: What you are looking for is a load balance. I personally use haproxy. If you trying to handle it by code, make no sense. Server1 will need to receive the request and handle it to Server2. Which it will create a bottle neck issue.

Comment: Also for that and to be used for seo Purpose